# LC3 Assembly Sum Input Numbers

Tags: assembly, lc3

I'm using LC3 Assembly to sum  ten numbers everything works well I FILL it as a constant but now I'm using input IN to get the input from the user and sum those inputs when the program finish 1 ten times entered is giving 490. Here is my code:

```
    .ORIG   x9375
    AND R2, R2, #0
    LD  R3, COUNTER 
REPEAT               ; Loop
    IN     ; Read a Value
    ADD R2, R2, R0 ; Sum the entered value
    ADD R3, R3, #-1 ; Decrement The loop
    Brp REPEAT
    HALT
    ST
COUNTER .FILL       x000A
    .END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are adding the *ASCII value* of `1` (which happens to be 49) 10 times, which would account for your result of 490.  So you'll need to convert it to its numerical value (which fortunately, can be done by subtracting 48, at least for single-digit numbers).

Comment: That's my problem is there a way to convert this value to decimal? if I don't enter always 1

Comment: But what if I don't input always 1. 2 in ascii is 50.

Comment: Then subtracting 48 from 50 will give you 2. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Thanks guys I was a bit confused with the values